# How do I rotate the login screen?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

So I am trying out the 14.04 and I keep both of my monitors in portrait mode. But the login splash is in landscape. But I can't seem to figure out how to rotate my login splash or where the config is for it? It is no longer in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

DBX12's answer is good. Let me add 2 details that I had to figure out in 18.10:

- Instead of `[SeatDefaults]` current versions expect `[Seat:*]`
- More importantly: I had to experiment a little with the above script using `logger` and then `xmessage` to conclude, that it does get called, it does set things right, but then its effect is unfortunately *undone* by unity-greeter.

I tried other greeters, and they all honor the solution and start up nicely rotated, except the default unity-greeter. I ended up using slick-greeter.

Comment: Spent more than an hour trying to get unity-greeter to rotate, finally saw this definitive "NO". Thanks for saving me from trying harder, I'll use another greeter too.

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr -o left
exit 0
```

into `/etc/lightdm/greeter_setup.sh` and add the line

```
greeter-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/greeter_setup.sh
```

to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` in the `[SeatDefaults]` Section.

All credits to SE user [falconer](https://askubuntu.com/users/221281/falconer) for his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/409317/564265)