# Lightdm issue after installing xmonad, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, xmonad

Yesterday I decided to install and try Xmonad on my laptop running a fairly fresh install of 14.04. After running an Xmonad session i decided to try the Gnome-xmonad (or something similar) option. All I saw was the background, and none of the key combinations for xmonad worked, so I restarted using the power button.

After that, the computer wouldn't boot into the Lightdm login, only a grey screen. I can ctrl+alt+F1 to open a shell. `sudo service lightdm restart` did not work and `start` only told me Lightdm was already running.

I read [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2165193), but it doesn't really apply to my issues. I tried adding `sleep 2` according to [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/ubuntu-lightdm-black-screen-when-using.html), but to no avail. I'm not really sure what I'm looking for right now, and decided to post this question before doing anything else.

I'll be available during the day to post logs and answer details.

Edit 1:
Output of `sudo lshw -c display`:

```
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:66 memory:b5000000-b53fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:6000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK208M [GeForce GT 730M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:65 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

Edit 2:
Running `sudo Xorg -configure` results in:

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already running for display 0
        if this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
        and start again.
```

Comment: Assuming you've already done a fresh install, this worked for me:
http://askubuntu.com/a/409866/42720

I goofed up xorg.conf in several directories and overwrote the backups, then ran into similar problems as you did.  It's easier to get Xmonad to accept Lightdm's monitor configuration that it is to use xorg.conf.  If your login screen uses that configuration file, then XMonad will catch it, but not otherwise, just in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to tty1, login
2. Stop lightdm:

   ```
   sudo stop lightdm
   ```
3. Purge lightdm then reinstall it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm
   sudo apt-get install lightdm
   ```
4. Start lightdm

   ```
   sudo start lightdm
   ```

Low graphic, try reconfigure Xorg

1. Switch to tty1, login
2. Stop lightdm:

   ```
   sudo stop lightdm
   ```
3. Create new Xorg configuration file:

   ```
   sudo Xorg -configure
   sudo mv /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
4. Reboot

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: After trying this it tries to boot into low-graphics mode and afterwards gets stuck on 'Restoring resolver state...'. Some more reading suggests driver issues (or possibly hardware). Any ideas?

Comment: Added the output to the original post.

Comment: There's no xorg.conf file, closest is xorg.conf.failsafe

Comment: Tried it, updated my post. How do I check if the server is still running, or should I go ahead and delete the file anyways?

Comment: Okay, I have created the xorg.conf and rebooted, but nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Try `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority; sudo restart lightdm`

Comment: Still nothing, lightdm shows up as running via `pidof`, but the screen remains grey. While this might very well be a driver issue, is it possible Xmonad modified any startup scripts, or is otherwise malfunctioning?

Comment: @user2837144; let confirm with 1st assumption "*Xmonad modified any startup scripts*", `sudo apt-get remove --purge xmonad` then `sudo restart lightdm`. If still the problem, 2st driver try nvidia driver, `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime mesa-utils vdpau-va-driver` , reboot

Comment: Still nothing, I'll try to do some more research tonight and if I can't fix it after that I'll just make a clean install.