# Black and white screen after "successful" LightDM login screen rotation in Ubuntu Mate 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, login-screen, mate, rotate-monitor

I have rotated LightDM login screen as suggested by [Stephen](https://askubuntu.com/a/466618) and got black and white greeter ([see photo](http://s4.postimg.org/c7jfg38j1/IMG_20150219_193636.jpg)).

Sometimes the problem disappears after login, but occasionally it remains on session.

I am running Ubuntu Mate 14.04 (efi boot) on Mac mini 6.2 desktop model (late 2012) with Dell 2007FP monitor.

Any ideas how to fix the issue?