# How to rotate screen at startup

Tags: command-line, autostart

I added a line 
`xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate right`
 in `/etc/rc.local` to rotate one of my monitors at startup, but it doesn't work (

Comment: Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/408302/rotated-monitor-login-screen-needs-rotation) option.

Comment: @vembutech thanks, maybe I'll find there what I'm looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### When to run this command

When you run this command from `/etc/rc.local`, it is too early. Xrandr commands (just like commands to change keyboard and mousepad- settings) need to be run *after* login, with a little break.

If you run them too early, before the desktop is ready for it, they will either break, miss target or are overruled by local procedures.

#### To run it on login, with a little break:

- If it is for one user, add the command:

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate right"
  ```

  to Startup Applications: Add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add.
- If it is for all users, create a file:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Set Screen Rotation
  Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate right"
  Type=Application
  ```

  save it as `setscreen.desktop` and copy it to `/etc/xdg/autostart`

#### Note

Possibly, you can play a little withe the value of 10 seconds, to optimize for your situation. If it is for a VM, you might need to set it longer, on a regular system, it could probably be shorter.