# Rotating login screeen on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login, 18.04

How do I rotate the login screen on Ubuntu 18.04 on first boot?

Comment: any luck on this?

Answer (score 1):

I followed [Steve Dee's advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/409866/527764) at [rotated monitor. login screen needs rotation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408302/rotated-monitor-login-screen-needs-rotation), but using `/var/lib/gdm3` instead - and adding appropriate permissions to the user's `.config` directory:

```
chmod 755 /home/<user>/.config
sudo ln -s /home/<user>/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/
sudo chown -h gdm:gdm /var/lib/gdm3/monitors.xml
sudo reboot
```

That worked for me.