# Login screen upside down

Tags: login, screen

I am using Ubuntu 22.04LTS on my GPD pocket 3.
The problem is that my login screen is upside-down.
I found this command: `sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/` I tried typing it into the terminal, but it does nothing.

I am planning on editing this file: `/etc/gdm3/Init/Default`

I used the xrandr command to find out my screen name and this was the output:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*XWAYLAND0 1920/172x1200/108+0+0  XWAYLAND0
```

I probably know the right line which is `xrandr --output SCREEN NAME --rotate inverted` but I am still unsure which file to edit and what my screen name is. Other posts talk about sddm, but there is no such file in my system.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/408302/rotated-monitor-login-screen-needs-rotation?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top

Comment: Thank you for your reply Hannu. Unfortunately there is no /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf in my system. Only file containing lightdm in my system is /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf . Is that the correct file? Thank you

Comment: Hmm...  that must be an "effect" of wayland being in use then; sorry can't help there.